# Generate a random sequence of two words

Tags: shell, zsh

How can I generate a random sequence of two words?

E.g. I want output like

```
act apt act act apt act act apt apt apt apt act
```

for words "apt" and "act" and sequence length 12

I came up with

```
 repeat 12 { if [ $(($(($RANDOM%10))%2)) -eq 1 ] ; then echo act ; else echo apt ; fi }
```

but it is quite long, especially the coin toss, is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `shuf` from GNU coreutils (in my case version 8.32):

```
shuf -r -n 12 -e act apt | tr '\n' ' '
```

From `man shuf`:

> shuf - generate random permutations
> -e, --echo : Treat each ARG as an input line
> -r, --repeat : Output lines can be repeated
> -n, --head-count=COUNT : Output at most COUNT lines

`shuf` alone prints one word per line, so we use `tr` to put all words into a single line by replacing the linebreaks by spaces.